# rxjava2: Flowable.unsafeCreate() vs Flowable.fromPublisher()

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

Provided that I implement my own `Publisher<T>` according to the reactive spec:

```
Publisher<Object> publisher = new MyAwesomelyReactivePublisher<>();
```

And now I want to hook it up with rxJava2 Flowable, what's the difference between:

```
Flowable.unsafeCreate(publisher);
```

and

```
Flowable.fromPublisher(publisher);
```

what's the use case for both? Reading Javadoc doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a JavaDoc difference you missed:

[unsafeCreate](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#unsafeCreate-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-)

> Throws:
>   IllegalArgumentException - if onSubscribe is a subclass of Flowable; such instances don't need conversion and is possibly a port remnant from 1.x or one should use hide() instead.

Beyond this, they are implemented the same way:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Flowable.java#L2131
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Flowable.java#L4257

Comment: Right. I did miss that indeed. Perhaps I lack the context of rxjava1. One thing I find a bit confusing is that the `Publisher` argument to `unsafeCreate()` is named `onSubscribe`... I guess this comes from the name of the only method on `Publisher` interface... still I find `source` on `fromPublisher()` less confusing. A digression. Thanks again for your answer